# Css3 dynamic added element not get animated

Tags: javascript, css, animation

As you see, I have list and button. When 'click' event triggered on the button, I dynamically add new element to the list. After new element is added to the list, I want to animate it on hover state with javascript, but it's not working. Everything is fine with hard coded list elements.

First solution which comes to mind is to hard code max number of the list elements and when hide what is unnecessary. But what, if i don't know max number of elements?

[Here is code](http://codepen.io/zzzTech/pen/WpGpmB)

Html

```
<section> 
  <div class='wrap'>
    <ul>
      <li class="box"></li>
      <li class="box stacked"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button> addBox </button>
</section>
```

Css/Sass

```
.box
  width: 100px
  height: 100px
  border: 1px solid black
  background: orange
  flex-basis: 1

.stacked
  margin-left: -50px

.up 
  animation-name: boxUp
  animation-duration: 300ms
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
  animation-delay: 0s
  animation-iteration-count: 1
  animation-direction: normal
  animation-fill-mode: forwards


@keyframes boxUp
  from
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  to
    transform: translate(0, -25px)
```

Javascript

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('ul').append($('<li>').attr('class', 'box stacked'));
});

$('.box').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('up');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('up');
});
```

Comment: Use delegation if it is a dynamically added element.

Comment: Thank you. Found a solution. $('ul').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('up');
});

Comment: yes, post that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a dynamically added element, it won't be present in the DOM at the time the event handlers are attached. So, you will have to use delegation from a parent which is present in the DOM right from the start (that is, use a parent which is a static content of the page and is present right from load).

You could use either the below:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', `.box`, function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('up');
});
```

or the one below which you ended up using:

```
$('ul').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li', function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('up'); 
});
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/RpGLYO)